# compile c source code into obj file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have one question about the compile c source file into obj file. the situation is: I got some source code from vendor, some lib from vendor and some obj file from vendor as well.

The makefile provide by vendor as well, and it use following way to define source:

```
${BUILD_LIB}_FILES += a.c \
b.c \
c.c
```

These three c files should firstly compile into obj file and then generate the lib file. However, vendor did NOT release me the `c.c` file for example, it only provide `c.o` to me, that means, I will first compile `a.c` and `b.c` into obj file, and use them together with `c.o` to generate lib file, but how it can be done by makefile?

**The confusing point is in makefile, it already list `c.c` should be in compile process (it add `c.c` into variable ${BUILD_LIB}_FILES)**, but if make can find there is pre-build `c.o`, it will NOT compile `c.c`(that means for my situation, whatever there is `c.c` or not, it compile successfully), WHY? From my understand, the `gcc` should compile ALL the source files, which already listed in that variable.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on other content of the makefile, that you'd have to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the features of make is that it won't rebuild code that's already been built. In your case, the C source code files won't be compiled because an object file already exists for those files. make sees that it needs to build a.c, b.c, and c.c and looks for a.o, b.o and c.o. Since the vendor provided those a.o, b.o, and c.o, it doesn't try to compile a.c, b.c, and c.c because it thinks they've already been compiled.

This feature is designed to reduce the amount of time it takes to recompile a large project when only a few files have changed. Very large projects can take minutes or hours or days to compile, so these savings can be great.

Comment: thank, I see if no c file and obj is there, makefile will not compile it

Answer (score -3):

As shown in [gcc command-line](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html), the **-c** option can be used to prevent gcc from linking. Once you got its ouput, you can use **ld** command to get the final a.out.

For example:

> gcc -c -o ab.o a.c b.c
>
> ld -o a.out -lc ab.o c.o

Comment: Do you realize that the link posted by you mentions that `-C: Do not discard comments. All comments are passed through to the output file, except for comments in processed directives, which are deleted along with the directive. ...`

Comment: Wrong: the relevant `gcc` option (to avoid linking) is in lowercase `gcc -c` (*not* `-C` !!); and using `gcc -Wall -g -c`  is useful....

Comment: but I think for my situation, it should be like `gcc -c -o a.c b.c c.c`, because ALL source file even NOT release to me, are listed in variable

Comment: @How Chen, I'm sorry but I don't think you did describe your intent clearly in the origin question.